# Matlab Gui For Webcam Capture and Screenshot

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, webcam

I am trying to make a GUI in Matlab with 2 views and 2 buttons.
In first view I want to show a video captured from webcam in real time and in second view I want to display a screenshot of video from first view when I press the "Capture image" button.

The problem is that when I press the "Capture image" button, the video and the screenshot switches their positions. I want the screenshot in the second view.

Here is my code:

```
    % --- Executes on button press in startStopCamera.
function startStopCamera_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject handle to startStopCamera (see GCBO)
% eventdata reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Start/Stop Camera
if strcmp(get(handles.startStopCamera,'String'),'Start Camera')
    % Camera is off. Change button string and start camera.
    set(handles.startStopCamera,'String','Stop Camera')
    axesHandle= findobj(gcf,'Tag','VideoCapture');
    preview(axesHandle, handles.video);

    start(handles.video)
    set(handles.captureImage,'Enable','on');
    % Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
else
    % Camera is on. Stop camera and change button string.
    set(handles.startStopCamera,'String','Start Camera')
   % axes(handles.VideoCapture);
    stop(handles.video)
    set(handles.captureImage,'Enable','off');
end

end
% --- Executes on button press in captureImage.
function captureImage_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to captureImage (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axesHandle= findobj(gcf,'Tag','Screenshot');
frame = getsnapshot(handles.video);
%frame = get(get(handles.Screenshot,'children'),'cdata'); % The current displayed frame

preview(axesHandle, frame);

end
```

Comment: How many figures are involved?  One figure with 2 axes or 2 figures?  I wouldn't use gcf in a callback and could be the problem if you have 2 figures. Better to use handles.FigureName where FigureName is the name of the figure assigned to the tag property in Guide.

Comment: I use 1 figure with 2 axes.